# Iterate and If value in dictionary A is larger than dictionary B then put in dictionary C?

Tags: python, pandas, finance, stockquotes

This code gets the current price of a stock and its current 21-day EMA.

```
import yfinance as yf 
import numpy as np
import bs4
import stockquotes
import pandas as pd

symbol_name = ['F', 'XOM']
symbol_data = {}
for symbol in symbol_name:
    ticker = stockquotes.Stock(symbol)
    today_price = ticker.current_price
    symbol_data[symbol] = today_price

print(symbol_data)

ema_data = {}
for x in symbol_name:
    symbol = yf.Ticker(x)
    quote = symbol.history(period='1mo',interval='1d') 
    quote = quote.sort_index()
    ema = 21
    quote['ewm'] = quote['Close'].ewm(span=ema,min_periods=0,adjust=False,ignore_na=False).mean()
    ema_quote = quote['ewm'].iloc[-1]
    ema_data[x] = ema_quote

print(ema_data)
```

Output:

```
{'F': 6.82, 'XOM': 40.01}
{'F': 6.912368574990924, 'XOM': 42.168230541483716}
```

My question is how to code the following:

```
If a one of the stock's EMA is lower than it's current price then put it into a new dictionary.
```

Can someone direct me on how to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dict1 = {'F': 6.82, 'XOM': 40.01} 
dict2 = {'F': 6.912368574990924, 'XOM': 42.168230541483716} 
dict3 = {}
for key in dict1.keys():
    if dict1.get(key) < dict2.get(key):
        dict3[key] = dict2.get(key)
```

Output :

```
{'F': 6.912368574990924, 'XOM': 42.168230541483716}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
for key in symbol_name:
    if ema_data[key] < symbol_data[key]:
        new_dict[key] = symbol_data[key]
```